# Can only use CSS class selector under one name

Tags: html, css

So, I'm very new to web design and have made a very simple code to test using classes.  But for some reason I can only get my class styling to show up under the name, "Block". It looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My document</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class = "Block"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

and for the css:

```
.Block {
    background-color: red;
    height: 28px;

    }
```

Why is only letting me use this class name and nothing else?  I'm using Chrome but I don't think that would be an issue would it?

Comment: You don't have any other classes in your html.

Comment: There's nothing special about the class name `Block`.  Can you include code that didn't work?

Comment: what do you expect to happen?

Comment: What happens if you both change the name of the class in css file and the name of the `class` attr of that `div` to something else as same. You dont see the same effects apply?

Comment: In your browser, go to the page in question and look at the source code.  Find the link to the style sheet and click on the file name to open it in the browser.  If you get an error, then your file is not where you expect and that is probably the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to change the name in your class as well. For example if you want it to work under the name header you need to change your CSS code to the code below and also change the class name in the HTML.

```css
.header {
    background-color: red;
    height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My document</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class = "header"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Were *you* going to change the class name to match the CSS? Still just seeing `"Block"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as expected. However, your style sheet may not be where you think that it is.

```css
.Block {
  background-color: red;
  height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Block"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried changing the class name to match both the .css and .txt files but nothing changed.  I was editing the html file with my css file showing and just reloading the html page every time I made a change to the css.  This worked fine as long as I didn't change "Block" to anything else or try adding a new div class to work on.  So eventually I just deleted my html page and made a new one with the changed code.  This actually worked, but it seems overly complicated that I would have to delete the page every time I want to make major changes.  I still must be missing something.

Comment: It is possible that you were seeing a cached copy of your .css file as cached by your browser.  You could try refreshing the page several times or clearing the cache manually.  Give that a try first, and you are right, this process should not be that complicated.